# Translating あくまで一応ですけどね

Tags: translation, meaning, words, usage

Translators say:

あくまで means: doggedly、insistently、persistently、stubbornly、to the bitter end、to the end、to the last、to the utmost

一応 means: tentatively、for the time being、in outline、just in case、once、one time、so far as it goes

I couldn’t understand how to solve this puzzle

Comment: 'Translators says...' . Which translator(s)? If you're using a dictionary, is there another definition of あくまで that you didn't include?

Comment: You provide 2 pieces from said puzzle. Have you tried to connect them? how? what was the result?

Comment: @user27280 if あく and まで separated; 開く (to open) 悪 (evil) 灰汁(scum,lye, harsh taste) 厭く (to tire, to loose interest)

Comment: @MathieuBouville if I could connect them I wouldn’t ask for help

Comment: Let me rephrase. Is there another definition of 「あくまで」(taken as a fixed expression) that you didn't include?  ...also, no answer yet regarding first question...

Comment: @user27280 only, consistently, thoroughness-> three this

Comment: @Alyona  The reason that I am asking you about alternate definitions is because, depending on what site or book you are using for reference, there might be a separate definition entry. 'Only' is an indication that you may have found it, as its meaning is so different from the others... We just want to make sure that you are using good resources well. If you don't tell us your sources it makes answering more complicated.

Comment: Yes I understand, I used: imiwa?; Reverso Context; ENJPDIctionary. I didn’t find alternate definitions((

Comment: @Alyona I'm not familiar with imiwa?. It might be okay for most things but probably doesn't go too far in depth. Reverso Context seems to not come up with their own content, but rather they get their sentences and translations from sources that might not always be that accurate. If by ENJPDictionary, you just mean a physical dictionary, the publisher of the Dictionary is quite relevant to quality...

Comment: .... You should visit (and bookmark) here: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese for more resources.  ...In the meantime, look at https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/あくまで , scroll down about halfway, and look for definition 2.

Comment: I think 'just in case" is appropriate for it.

Comment: @user27280 thank for providing excellent resources, it will help in future learning))

Comment: @YuuichiTam omg, it was so simple, thank you so much 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very hard to give a correct translation without any context, but あくまで一応ですけどね usually means something like "You know, this is just for making sure", "Well, I know this is not mandatory/critical", "I'm suggesting this merely as a backup, after all", "I don't have a strong opinion, though", etc., depending on what 一応 is actually referring to.

あくまで is a difficult expression, in this context it's closer to "just" and/or "after all". Basically it's emphasizing the meaning of 一応. See: [Meaning of あくまで in あくまで私個人の意見です](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11363/5010)

Comment: Previous one was : 送受信を司るICカードを抜いて起動したのか機転が利くな

Comment: @Alyona Still inconclusive to me, but maybe this 一応 can mean something like "It's merely a quick/tentative fix."